# Find line number from HCL coordinates in Terraform file

Tags: go, terraform, hcl

Given a Golang function:

```
func GetLineNumber(ctx context.context, file []byte, search string) 
    (line int, found bool, err error) {...}
```

Given a Terraform file:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "files" {
  bucket = "legal_files"

  tags = {
    "application" = "backup"
  }
}
```

And this search input:

```
resource.aws_s3_bucket.files.tags.application
```

My function (written in Go) needs to return the line number and whether the item was found:

```
return 5, true, nil
```

I plan to use `github.com/hashicorp/hcl/v2` and its [ParseHCL](https://github.com/hashicorp/hcl2/blob/fb75b32/hclparse/parser.go#L40) function. It gives me a struct I can navigate but it's complex and tedious given all the interface abstractions and multiple types involved in the returned `hcl.File`. Before I jump in, I wondered: is there a paved way to do this?

Comment: I think ParseHCL would not assist here with returning a line number. I think what you really need here is some kind of AST or something like that, and you probably need the HCL2 module itself for that.